# making text appear delayed

Tags: java, text

I want to make text appear in the following way:

```
H
wait 0.1 seconds
He
wait 0.1 seconds
Hel
wait 0.1 seconds
Hell
wait 0.1 seconds
Hello
```

But I'm not sure how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm hoping that I will be able to do it in a way that doesn't require me to make a System.out.print(); for each letter.

EDIT 3: Here's my code. EDIT 4: No more problems, it worked perfectly, thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class GameBattle
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    printWithDelays("HELLO", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);
}

public static void printWithDelays(String data, TimeUnit unit, long delay)
        throws InterruptedException {
    for (char ch:data.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(ch);
        unit.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first error message is telling you that you can't put a `public static void main` there - you probably already have one elsewhere.

Comment: The message still appears after I remove the other public static void main.

Comment: I will need to see your code, at least first 50 rows to see where exactly you put my code. I suspect you put `main` method inside other method. There may be other reasons for your errors but without seeing your code it would be very hard to fix them.

Comment: @user2974798 do you know how to program in Java at all?!? or are you just not thinking about what you are doing?

Comment: I know a few things but I am clueless about how to do this, I can solve the new error, I'm either missing or have an extra "}".

Comment: You are missing one `}` at the end. If you have other code inside `GameBattle.java` file then it will cause lot of problems. You should use indentation in your code to see such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print each letter in `0.1s` interval using `Thread.sleep` or more readable way (at least for me) using `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep` for example

```
print first letter;
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
print second letter
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
...
```

**[Update]**

> I'm hoping that I will be able to do it in a way that doesn't require me to make a System.out.print(); for each letter.

I don't see any reason not to do it this way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    printWithDelays("HELLO", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);
}

public static void printWithDelays(String data, TimeUnit unit, long delay)
        throws InterruptedException {
    for (char ch : data.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(ch);
        unit.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I got a series of errors in upon compiling.

Comment: What kind of errors? Did you add `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` to imports?

Comment: @user2974798 Let me know when you do this. If you prefer you can post link to http://pastebin.com/ with your code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Thread.sleep` function to pause execution.

```
System.out.print("H");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.print("E");
...etc
```

Of course, you'd probably want to put all of that into a loop, but Thread.sleep is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 try {
  Thread.sleep(timeInMiliseconds); // In your case it would be: Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "Hello";

for(int i=1; i<=text.length();i++){
   System.out.println(text.substring(0, i));
    try {
       Thread.sleep(100); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit:
if you want only 1 character by 1, than:

```
for(int i=0; i<text.length();i++){
   System.out.print(""+text.characterAt(i));
    try {
       Thread.sleep(100); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what have you asked in your question: H
wait 0.1 seconds
He
wait 0.1 seconds
Hel
wait 0.1 seconds
Hell
wait 0.1 seconds
Hello

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer, I want it to display the word "Hello," with a brief pause in between each letter.