# how to make letters appear one by one in java?

Tags: java

I'd like to make my letters appear one by,
i'm using the latest version of java, any ideas?
Just for a simple assignment for school, we need to make a vending machine and i thought it was cool to give it an old windows vibe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about printing characters one by one and putting Thread::sleep between prints? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882885/making-text-appear-delayed

Comment: Before asking, you should try it yourself and then post where you failed. This site doesn't do your homework. Additionally, you should provide some more information about the context. What letters should appear? Where do they come from?

Comment: Here's the thing, i really don't know where to start. The characters are pretty much all the stand characters that can be typed from a regular qwerty keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread sleep in for loop

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {

    String test = "my letters appear one by one";
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(test.charAt(i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);    // time interval in milliseconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```