# Java system out print slow

Tags: java

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get message, convert to char array

        System.out.print("Hello world , this is a test.");

    }
}
```

How can I do so that the message printed in the console does not go out directly, that it goes little by little

Comment: What do you mean by little by little?

Comment: implement a timer, or a sleep, between the printing of each char

Comment: Possibly related: [making text appear delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19882885)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's put the message in a separate variable.

Step 1:

```
String message = "Hello world , this is a test.";
System.out.print(message);
```

Now, let's print the message letter by letter, instead of printing it at once. We'll make a loop that counts from 0 to the length of the message.

Step 2:

```
String message = "Hello world , this is a test.";

for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
}
```

Then, inside the loop, we get the i'th character and print it.

Step 3:

```
String message = "Hello world , this is a test.";

for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
    char ch = message.charAt(i);
    System.out.print(ch);
}
```

Now, the computer runs very fast so the message will still appear at once when we run this. To make it go slower, we have to add a pause between printing each of the characters. We can do this by using `Thread.sleep()`:

Step 4:

```
String message = "Hello world , this is a test.";

for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
    char ch = message.charAt(i);
    System.out.print(ch);
    Thread.sleep(100); // Sleep 100ms (0.1 seconds)
}
```

There's still one thing we need to do. The method `Thread.sleep()` may throw an `InterruptedException`, and Java requires us to deal with that. The simplest way to do that is to specify that the `main` method may throw this exception. So the whole `main` method becomes:

Step 5:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String message = "Hello world , this is a test.";

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        char ch = message.charAt(i);
        System.out.print(ch);
        Thread.sleep(100); // Sleep 100ms (0.1 seconds)
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG thanks so much that is what i need !!! amazing !

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
private static void slowPrint(String string) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] strings = string.split(" ");
    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.print(s + ' ');
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: the op was looking char by char print.